Is it okay to pray to god to destory hell?
It is a win win situation if Hell is destroyed. So what about praying to god to destory Hell so that all Jin and Mankind will enter paradise. So is it wrong according to Quran to pray to god to remove the Hell and judgement and pray to god to give highest paradise for all human kind and Jinn?

why the DV? it seems quite a sound question

As long as there are hateful people wishing other people to hell, there is a reason for hell to exist. Pray instead to remove sin and hate.

No, it is not. It is forbidden to pray to Allah to forgive the disbelievers:

ما كان للنبي والذين آمنوا أن يستغفروا للمشركين ولو كانوا أولي قربى من بعد ما تبين لهم أنهم أصحاب الجحيم
It is not for the Prophet and those who have believed to ask forgiveness for the polytheists, even if they were relatives, after it has become clear to them that they are companions of Hellfire.
— Quran 9:113

And in this dua you are asking Allah to 'destory hell' and ' give highest paradise for all human kind and Jinn' which implies that you are asking Him to forgive the disbelievers as well.

Allah, the Wise, has invited people to judge the issue by themselves in His Quran:

قُلْ لَا يَسْتَوِي الْخَبِيثُ وَ الطَّيِّبُ وَ لَوْ أَعْجَبَكَ كَثْرَةُ الْخَبِيثِ فَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ يَا أُولِي الْأَلْبَابِ لَعَلَّكُمْ تُفْلِحُونَ [المائده، ۱۰۰]
Say, 'Not equal are the evil and the good, although the abundance of evil might impress you.' So fear Allah, O you of understanding, that you may be successful.
مَثَلُ الْفَرِيقَيْنِ كَالْأَعْمَيٰ وَ الْأَصَمِّ وَ الْبَصِيرِ وَ السَّمِيعِ هَلْ يَسْتَوِيَانِ مَثَلًا أَفَلَا تَذَكَّرُونَ [هود، ۲۴]
These two kinds (of men) may be compared to the blind and deaf, and those who can see and hear well. Are they equal when compared? Will ye not then take heed?
... أَفَاتَّخَذْتُمْ مِنْ دُونِهِ أَوْلِيَاءَ لَا يَمْلِكُونَ لِأَنْفُسِهِمْ نَفْعًا وَ لَا ضَرًّا قُلْ هَلْ يَسْتَوِي الْأَعْمَيٰ وَ الْبَصِيرُ أَمْ هَلْ تَسْتَوِي الظُّلُمَاتُ وَ النُّورُ أَمْ جَعَلُوا لِلَّهِ شُرَكَاءَ ... [الرعد، ۱۶]
... Say: 'Do ye then take (for worship) protectors other than Him, such as have no power either for good or for harm to themselves?' Say: 'Are the blind equal with those who see? Or the depths of darkness equal with light?' Or do they assign to Allah partners? ...
وَ ضَرَبَ اللَّهُ مَثَلًا رَجُلَيْنِ أَحَدُهُمَا أَبْكَمُ لَا يَقْدِرُ عَلَيٰ شَيْءٍ وَ هُوَ كَلٌّ عَلَيٰ مَوْلَاهُ أَيْنَمَا يُوَجِّهْهُ لَا يَأْتِ بِخَيْرٍ هَلْ يَسْتَوِي هُوَ وَ مَنْ يَأْمُرُ بِالْعَدْلِ وَ هُوَ عَلَيٰ صِرَاطٍ مُسْتَقِيمٍ [النّحل، ۷۶]
And Allah presents an example of two men, one of them dumb and unable to do a thing, while he is a burden to his guardian. Wherever he directs him, he brings no good. Is he equal to one who commands justice, while he is on a straight path?
وَ مَا يَسْتَوِي الْأَعْمَيٰ وَ الْبَصِيرُ، وَ لَا الظُّلُمَاتُ وَ لَا النُّورُ، وَ لَا الظِّلُّ وَ لَا الْحَرُورُ، وَ مَا يَسْتَوِي الْأَحْيَاءُ وَ لَا الْأَمْوَاتُ ... [فَاطِر: ۱۹۹-۲۲]
Not equal are the blind and the seeing, Nor are the darknesses and the light, Nor are the shade and the heat, And not equal are the living and the dead. ...
أَمَّنْ هُوَ قَانِتٌ آنَاءَ اللَّيْلِ سَاجِدًا وَ قَائِمًا يَحْذَرُ الْآخِرَةَ وَ يَرْجُو رَحْمَةَ رَبِّهِ قُلْ هَلْ يَسْتَوِي الَّذِينَ يَعْلَمُونَ وَ الَّذِينَ لَا يَعْلَمُونَ إِنَّمَا يَتَذَكَّرُ أُولُوا الْأَلْبَابِ [الزّمر، ۹]
Is one who worships devoutly during the hour of the night prostrating himself or standing (in adoration), who takes heed of the Hereafter, and who places his hope in the Mercy of his Lord - (like one who does not)? Say: 'Are those equal, those who know and those who do not know? It is those who are endued with understanding that receive admonition.
وَ مَا لَكُمْ أَلَّا تُنْفِقُوا فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ وَ لِلَّهِ مِيرَاثُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ الْأَرْضِ؟ لَا يَسْتَوِي مِنْكُمْ مَنْ أَنْفَقَ مِنْ قَبْلِ الْفَتْحِ وَ قَاتَلَ، أُولَئِكَ أَعْظَمُ دَرَجَةً مِنَ الَّذِينَ أَنْفَقُوا مِنْ بَعْدُ وَ قَاتَلُوا، وَ كُلًّا وَعَدَ اللَّهُ الْحُسْنَيٰ وَ اللَّهُ بِمَا تَعْمَلُونَ خَبِيرٌ [الحدید، ۱۰]
and why do you not spend in the cause of Allah while to Allah belongs the heritage of the heavens and the earth? Not equal among you are those who spent before the conquest and fought [and those who did so after it]. Those are greater in degree than they who spent afterwards and fought. But to all Allah has promised the best [reward]. And Allah, with what you do, is Acquainted.

and eventually

لَا يَسْتَوِي أَصْحَابُ النَّارِ وَ أَصْحَابُ الْجَنَّةِ أَصْحَابُ الْجَنَّةِ هُمُ الْفَائِزُونَ [الحشر، ۲۰]
Not equal are the companions of the Fire and the companions of Paradise. The companions of Paradise, that will achieve Felicity.

Being JUST makes the Hell a necessity. However, Hell in Islam is a place to purify those who have not already purified in Dunya, nor at their death, nor in Barzakh, and nor in Qiyamah. The majority of those submitted to the Hell will be eventually set free from the Hell, and enter a level of the Heaven, even if it takes thousands or millions of years for their pause in the Hell. However, there will (probably) remain a group of wrongdoers in the Hell eternally with no end, but THIS is still a manifestation of Allah being the Entirely Mercifull (الرّحمن), although it is not so apparent if we have not dive deep in studying the issue (cf the 2024 update of this answer for an arguable hint) ...
Islam has several levels, at the bottom is accepting the religion and trying to submit to Allah, at the top Muslims should not only accept the orders but also be pleased with them. This is a level in the Heaven called "رضوان" or "جنة الّرضوان", wherein Allah is pleased by them and they are pleased with Allah. For example Allah AwJ has stated in His Quran: "يَا أَيَّتُهَا النَّفْسُ الْمُطْمَئِنَّةُ، ارْجِعِي إِلَيٰ رَبِّكِ رَاضِيَةً مَرْضِيَّةً" which is translated into "O reassured soul, Come back thou to thy Lord,- well pleased (thyself), and well-pleasing unto Him!". The good practice in Islam is to accept what Allah the Wise has ordered and has arranged for His creation and ruling all the affairs, being Him the entirely Merciful, the Most Gracious, and the Free of all wants. But the best practice, is not only to admit that, but also to be pleased with, remembering that He knows and we are the one who may forget or be ignorant. For example Allah has stated:

كُتِبَ عَلَيْكُمُ الْقِتَالُ وَ هُوَ كُرْهٌ لَكُمْ وَ عَسَيٰ أَنْ تَكْرَهُوا شَيْئًا وَ هُوَ خَيْرٌ لَكُمْ وَ عَسَيٰ أَنْ تُحِبُّوا شَيْئًا وَ هُوَ شَرٌّ لَكُمْ وَ اللَّهُ يَعْلَمُ وَ أَنْتُمْ لَا تَعْلَمُونَ [البقرة، ۲۱۶
]
Fighting is prescribed for you, and ye dislike it. But it is possible that ye dislike a thing which is good for you, and that ye love a thing which is bad for you. But Allah knoweth, and ye know not.

‌Being pleased with the design Allah has put forward for His creation is why the Muslims always try to pray Allah in a way which goes well with the thread Himself has introduced us. For example Allah has stated "إِنَّ اللَّهَ وَ مَلَائِكَتَهُ يُصَلُّونَ عَلَي النَّبِيِّ يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا صَلُّوا عَلَيْهِ وَ سَلِّمُوا تَسْلِيمًا", translated as "Allah and His angels send blessings on the Prophet: O ye that believe! Send ye blessings on him, and salute him with all respect", so we always send peace to him and his household by praying to Allah in a way that we take part in what Allah Himself do and know what that means best, by saying "اللهم صلّ علیٰ محمد و آل محمد", i.e. by asking Allah Himself to send Peace to him and his household, and this while Allah has stated that He do, whether we ask for it or not, but this way we show our being pleased with Him doing so, and trying to best obey it by asking Allah to do it on our behalf! Aksing Allah to curse the enemies of Him and his prophets and the believers in also in that regard, and this latter praying is indeed insisting on accepting that the Hell is necessary and we are praying for Allah sending whoever He will to the Hell, and keep them there for any duration of time that He wants. Maybe it is good to also point out how Christ PBUH responds back in front of Allah in Qiyamah when he is asked questions about his people, as narrated by Quran:

وَ إِذْ قَالَ اللَّهُ يَا عِيسَي ابْنَ مَرْيَمَ أَأَنْتَ قُلْتَ لِلنَّاسِ اتَّخِذُونِي وَ أُمِّيَ إِلَهَيْنِ مِنْ دُونِ اللَّهِ قَالَ سُبْحَانَكَ مَا يَكُونُ لِي أَنْ أَقُولَ مَا لَيْسَ لِي بِحَقٍّ إِنْ كُنْتُ قُلْتُهُ فَقَدْ عَلِمْتَهُ تَعْلَمُ مَا فِي نَفْسِي وَ لَا أَعْلَمُ مَا فِي نَفْسِكَ إِنَّكَ أَنْتَ عَلَّامُ الْغُيُوبِ ... وَ كُنْتُ عَلَيْهِمْ شَهِيدًا مَا دُمْتُ فِيهِمْ فَلَمَّا تَوَفَّيْتَنِي كُنْتَ أَنْتَ الرَّقِيبَ عَلَيْهِمْ وَ أَنْتَ عَلَيٰ كُلِّ شَيْءٍ شَهِيدٌ ... إِنْ تُعَذِّبْهُمْ فَإِنَّهُمْ عِبَادُكَ وَ إِنْ تَغْفِرْ لَهُمْ فَإِنَّكَ أَنْتَ الْعَزِيزُ الْحَكِيمُ
And [beware the Day] when Allah will say, 'O Jesus, Son of Mary, did you say to the people, 'Take me and my mother as deities besides Allah?'' He will say, 'Exalted are You! It was not for me to say that to which I have no right. If I had said it, You would have known it. You know what is within myself, and I do not know what is within Yourself. Indeed, it is You who is Knower of the unseen. ... And I was a witness over them as long as I was among them; but when You took me up, You were the Observer over them, and You are, over all things, Witness. ... If You should punish them - indeed they are Your servants; but if You forgive them - indeed it is You who is the Exalted in Might, the Wise.


UPDATE. In Dua Kumayl (actually Hazrat Khidhr's Dua, taught to Kumayl-ibn-Zyad by Imam Ali PBUH) we read:

فَبِالْيَقِينِ أَقْطَعُ لَوْلا مَا حَكَمْتَ بِهِ مِن تَعْذِيبِ
جَاحِدِيكَ، وَقَضَيْتَ بِهِ مِنْ إِخْلاَدِ مُعَانِدِيكَ، لَجَعَلْتَ
النَّارَ كُلَّهَا بَرْداً وَّسَلاَماً، وَمَا كَانَ لأَحَدٍ فِيهَا
مَقَرّاً وَّلا مُقَاماً، لَّكِنَّكَ تَقَدَّسَتْ أَسْمَاؤُكَ أَقْسَمْتَ
أَنْ تَمْلأَهَا مِنَ الْكَافِرِينَ، مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ
أَجْمَعِينَ، وَأَن تُخَلِّدَ فِيهَا الْمُعَانِدِينَ، وَأَنتَ جَلَّ
ثَنَاؤُكَ قُلْتَ مُبْتَدَئاً، وَّتَطَوَّلْتَ بِالإِنْعَامِ
مُتَكَرِّماً: فَمَن كَانَ مُؤْمِنًا كَمَن كَانَ فَاسِقًا ۚ لَّا
يَسْتَوُونَ
So I declare with certainty that were it not for what You hast
decreed concerning the chastisement of Your deniers, And what You hast
foreordained concerning the everlasting home of those who stubbornly
resist, You wouldst make the Fire, all of it, coolness and safety,
And no one would have a place of rest or abode within it.  But
You—holy are Your Names—hast sworn that You wilt fill it with the
unbelievers, Both Jinn and men together, And that You wilt place those
who stubbornly resist therein forever. And You— majestic is Your
eulogy— said at the beginning and wernt gracious through kindness as a
favour, "What? Is he who has been believer like unto him who has been
ungodly? They are not equal"

